# Unit test webapi controller with response headers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-web-api2, moq

I'm trying to learn webapi and have stumbled across a problem. The training course I was doing showed how to do paging by returning a response header with the next and previous link. However it uses `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add()` to send back the next link, previous link, and total pages.

I am also trying to implement unit tests for the controllers. Problem seems to be that the `HttpContext.Current` is `null` when running through a unit test. I read somewhere that I shouldn't be `HttpContext.Current` for webapi as it's not testable, but I'm not sure what I should be using instead.

Here is my contoller code:

```
public partial class CandidateManagerController
{
    private readonly ICandidateManager _candidateManagerV2;

    public CandidateManagerController(ICandidateManager candidateManager)
    {
        _candidateManagerV2 = candidateManager;
    }

    [VersionedRoute("CandidateManager", 2, Name="CandidateManagerV2")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int page = 1, int pageSize = 1)
    {
        try
        {
            var totalCount = 0;
            var totalPages = 0;

            var result = _candidateManagerV2.GetCandidates(out totalCount, out totalPages, page, pageSize);

            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request);


            var prevLink = page > 1
                ? urlHelper.Link("CandidateManagerV2",
                    new
                    {
                        page = page - 1,
                        pageSize = pageSize,
                    })
                : "";


            var nextLink = page < totalPages ? urlHelper.Link("CandidateManagerV2",
                new
                {
                    page = page + 1,
                    pageSize = pageSize
                }) : "";

            var paginationHeader = new
            {
                currentPage = page,
                pageSize = pageSize,
                totalCount = totalCount,
                totalPages = totalPages,
                previousPageLink = prevLink,
                nextPageLink = nextLink
            };

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader));



            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my unit test. Please note I'm using Nunit and Moq:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CandidateManagerControllerV2Tests
{


    [Test]
    [Category("CandidateManagerController Unit Tests")]
    public void Should_Return_List_Of_Candidate_Objects()
    {

        var testList = new List<Candidate>();
        testList.Add(new Candidate() { CandidateId = 1, Name = "Mr", Surname = "Flibble" });
        testList.Add(new Candidate() { CandidateId = 2, Name = "Arnold", Surname = "Rimmer" });

        var totalCount = 0;
        var totalPages = 0;
        var mockManager = new Mock<ICandidateManager>();
        mockManager.Setup(x => x.GetCandidates(out totalCount, out totalPages, It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(testList);

        var controller = new CandidateManagerController(mockManager.Object);
        SetupControllerForTests(controller);

        var result = controller.Get(1, 1);
    }

    private static void SetupControllerForTests(ApiController controller)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/candidatemanager");
        var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
        var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "products" } });

        controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
        controller.Request = request;
        controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
        controller.ActionContext=new HttpActionContext();
    }

}
```

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me. It could be that I've been led down a wrong path with the way to implement paging. However it is likely that I'd need to add a response header for something any way.

Comment: Take a look at: https://vanbrughsoftware.wordpress.com/2016/06/18/unit-testing-controller-response-headers-in-asp-net-core-1-0-rc2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid coupling yourself to `HttpContext`.

Here is another approach to how you can set the header and still be able to unit test it as you intended. You create a `HttpResponseMessage`, add headers as needed and then create a `ResponseMessageResult` from it:

```cs
//...code removed for brevity

var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);

response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader));

IHttpActionResult ok = ResponseMessage(response);

return ok;
```

You should also note that your controller setup will cause a null reference error when creating your UrlHelper because you are resetting the controller's `Request` to null when you assign the default `ActionContext`

```cs
private static void SetupControllerForTests(ApiController controller) {
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/candidatemanager");
    var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
    var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "products" } });

    controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
    controller.Request = request;
    controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
    //commented this out as it was causing Request to be null
    //controller.ActionContext=new HttpActionContext();
}
```

The following test passed when checking for the `X-Pagination` header

```cs
public async Task Should_Return_Paged_List_Of_Candidate_Objects() {
    //Arrange
    var testList = new List<Candidate>();
    testList.Add(new Candidate() { CandidateId = 1, Name = "Mr", Surname = "Flibble" });
    testList.Add(new Candidate() { CandidateId = 2, Name = "Arnold", Surname = "Rimmer" });

    var totalCount = 0;
    var totalPages = 0;
    var mockManager = new Mock<ICandidateManager>();
    mockManager.Setup(x => x.GetCandidates(out totalCount, out totalPages, It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(testList);

    var controller = new CandidateManagerController(mockManager.Object);
    SetupControllerForTests(controller);

    //Act
    var response = await controller.Get(1, 1).ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(response, typeof(HttpResponseMessage));
    Assert.IsTrue(response.Headers.Contains("X-Pagination"));
}
```

Comment: how can I test like this, if Request holds a Stream for example? In a multipart context. I would like to like to test like this, but I ended up using in memory HttpServer, so Request is handled like a real world situation

Comment: @ntohl just populate the request with what is needed to exercise the system under test. Set the request's Content property accordingly.

Comment: I have managed that. Thanks. But after adding CORS to the equality, I had to check headers, if they are generated correctly from `[EnableCors("*", "Origin", "POST")]`, and also I couldn't check what my custom MessageHandler did to the response.

Comment: Is  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute mandatory if I am using attribute routing instead of conventional routing?

Answer (score 3):

To test your response headers you need to do the following:

1. Initialize your controller with a ControllerContext in `TestInitialize`
2. Call the controller where you add the custom header
3. Assert it in the `TestMethod`

> It only works if you add your header in the controller class: `HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("x-custom-header", "value");`

Example:

```cs
public class MyControllerTests
{
    private MyController _controller;
    
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _controller= new MyController();
        _controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(),
        };
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetAsyncShouldContainCutomHeader()
    {
        // Act
        await _controller.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(_controller.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-custom-header"));
        Assert.IsTrue(_controller.Response.Headers["x-custom-header"].Equals("value"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Saved my day. HttpContext gets null after mocking